# Firebase nodejs function set cookie TypeError: option sameSite is invalid

Tags: express, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

**EDIT:
This seems like a bug so I added an issue** https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/653

When handling request on deployed cloud function and setting cookie with sameSite 'none' option the 'TypeError: option sameSite is invalid' error is thrown.

```
const options = {
                    secure: true,
                    sameSite: 'none'
                };
res.cookie('session', cookieValue, options);
```

I could set a boolean value but that is not enough.

Comment: I think the string 'none' is causing issues here. How about trying None, without quotation marks as shown here https://web.dev/samesite-cookies-explained/#changes-to-the-default-behavior-without-samesite

Comment: thanks, but .cookie method requires CookieOptions interface that has definition sameSite?: boolean | 'lax' | 'strict' | 'none';

Answer (score 4):

This is because of express version `4.16.x` which uses cookie `0.3.0`, which does not support **`sameSite:'none'`** option in cookies.

This support was added to the cookie npm version `0.4.x` & above. To fix your issue, you can simply update expres, which is uses cookie version `0.4.x` & above.

JFYR: Express Changelog: https://expressjs.com/en/changelog/4x.html

Comment: <3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3

Comment: To build on your answer, one might want to also check the `express-session` dependency, where starting from `1.17.0` 'none' option is supported. As of writing the latest version is `1.17.3`